# Sorting panels based on JLabel contents

Tags: java, jpanel

I have the following declarations:

```
public JPanel compPanes[] = new JPanel[13];
public JPanel userPanes[] = new JPanel[13];
public int cNum = 0;
```

Now, I have a method where it adds four `JPanels` to another panel until it has four panels (Just a shorter, alternative version of the method):

```
public void addCompPanels(JPanel compPane)
{
        Random rand = new Random();
        cPanelNum = (int)(Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 1));
        compPanes[cNum] = new JPanel();
        compPanes[cNum].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 90));
        compPanes[cNum].add(new JLabel());
        JLabel label = (JLabel)compPanes[cNum].getComponent(0);     
        label.setFont(pickFont);
        label.setText("" +cPanelNum);
        compPanes[cNum].setBackground(color);       
        compPane.add(compPanes[cNum]);
        compPane.revalidate();
        cNum++; 
}
```

After adding a total of four panels, I want to sort the panels according to the integer value of their `JLabel`.

I experimented a bit with how you sort integers, trying if it would work (because I thought it works on `JPanels`). But it seem to be not applicable since it returns a null pointer exception.

```
for(int i = 0; i < compPanes.length; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j < compPanes.length; j++){

        JLabel lblOne = (JLabel)compPanes[i].getComponent(0);
        JLabel lblTwo = (JLabel)compPanes[j].getComponent(0);

        if((Integer.parseInt(lblOne.getText())) >(Integer.parseInt(lblTwo.getText())));
        {
            tempPanel = compPanes[i];
            compPanes[i] = compPanes[j];
            compPanes[j] = tempPanel;
            compPane.add(compPanes[i]);
            compPane.add(compPanes[j]);             
            compPane.revalidate();  
            compPane.repaint();                                     
        }
    }
}
```

A visual representation:

Before swap

[image]

After swap

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: If you get an NPE then analyze and fix that if appropriate. Besides just sort the panels using `Collections.sort()` along with a `Comparator<JPanel>` and compare the label values there (and if they can be null you can handle that as well).

Comment: Can you please provide an example to demonstrate the logic?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for an example I'll add a simple one. Note that it will be somewhat pseudocode so you'll have to adapt it to your needs (the main intention is to teach not to provide readily usable code):

```
Collection<JPanel> panels = ...;
Collections.sort( panels, new Comparatory<JPanel>() {
  public int compare( JPanel o1, JPanel o2) {
    JLabel l1 = o1.getLabel();
    JLabel l2 = o2.getLabel();

    if( l1 != null && l2 != null ) {
      //note that the text might be null as well, so handle this
      //further note that if the text represents multi-digit numbers you might have to parse them first
      return l1.getText().compareTo( l2.getText() );
    }
    else ... //decide how to handle null labels
  }
};
```

If you directly want to sort the arrays use `Arrays.sort( array, comparator )`. Just note that I'm not sure whether you'd interfere with some Swing component internals that way (and I can't dig into Swing to check that right now).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short test program of sorting JPanel based on JLabel text using Comparator just like above suggestion

```
 import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

import javax.swing.*;


class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                createAndShowGui(); 
            }
        });
    }



    private static void createAndShowGui()
    {
        JPanel panel[] = new JPanel[4];

        for(int  i = 0; i != panel.length; ++i)
        {
            int num = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 1));
            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("" + num);
            panel[i] = new JPanel();
            panel[i].add(lbl);      
            panel[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        }

        Arrays.sort(panel, new JPanelSort());


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sort JPanel Example");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        for(int i = 0; i != panel.length; ++i)
            frame.add(panel[i]);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   



    private static class JPanelSort implements Comparator<JPanel>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(JPanel arg0, JPanel arg1) 
        {
            String firstNum = ((JLabel) arg0.getComponent(0)).getText();
            String secondNum = ((JLabel) arg1.getComponent(0)).getText();

            return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(firstNum), Integer.parseInt(secondNum));
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I would try this example and give you an update! :)